# new to selenium-webdriver, switching from one window to another

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Currently I have started to use selenium 2.0/web-driver for  automation testing for the company that I work for.

Currently I have about 20 tests developed for testing, but when I run the tests they open a new browser window for each test.

Unfortunately though I need the new user registration/login info which is executed in the first test to be used in the rest of the tests since I'm testing a webstore/shopping cart.

My question is, is there a way to either stop having all the new browser windows opening or close the window and then place the focus back to the first window where the new user was registered and logged in?  Through doing some research before writing a question here I found out about the

`driver.getWindowHandles();`

which I have being run in the registration test case and then

`driver.switchTo().window("handle");`
which I have being run in the second test case and I thought should have put the focus back to the first window.
I'm also using the `driver.close();` to close the additional windows that are being created, but I would prefer that they don't even open in the first place.

Comment: What browser you are using?

Comment: Currently learning this on firefox, but I will need to expand this to chrome, IE 8 - 11, safari, as well as mobile emulation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correct what you need - add procedure with @Before annotation and inside this procedure open the driver. Then add procedure with @After annotation and then close the driver. Inside your tests (with the @Test annotation) you need use driver.get. In this case the new windows will not be opened.